# R: Connect RSudio Server to MySQL(local machine) remotly using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, database-connection

I have a script running on RStudio Server. I want to connect my RSTudio to MySQL database existing in another server(my localhost), I used these lines:

```
  library(RMySQL)

  mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='myusername', password='mypasswd', dbname='my_db', host='IP of the server in which mysql exists')
```

But I have this error:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP of the server in which mysql exists' (110)
```

In MySQL Server I granted the privileges to the server hosting my RStudio Server:

```
  grant all privileges on *.* to remoteuser@IPofRStudioServer identified by "userpassword";
```

And I commented this line in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
  bind-address      = 127.0.0.1
```

Can you please help me ?

Comment: is mysql running on that ip? is that IP reachable from your client machine? is mysql configured for TCP connections? Is mysql's port reachable? blah blah blah...

Comment: @MarcB I am using the IP adress of my client machine. Actually, I want to connect RStudio server to my client machine. But how can I know that  mysql configured for TCP connections? Is mysql's port reachable?... Thank you

Comment: in real world terms, you're doing "I'm trying to drive to my friend's house, but I"m entering my home address into the GPS. Why is my friend not at home at my house?". maybe if you tried your mysql server's IP instead...

Comment: @marcB you didn't understand me : mysql database exists on my client machine, there's no mysql server's IP.

Comment: ah. then in that case, did you confirm that mysql is configured for tcp connections, and it's listening on that ip?

Comment: @marcB I entered to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (I'm using ubuntu 14.10), and I commented `skip-external-locking` line. In that case, mysql server is accepting remote access ? I don't know what to do else.

Comment: `skip-external-locking` has nothing to do with networking. `skip-networking`, on the other hand...